# How to call Service location

Tags: java, android, location

I need to get user location each 5 minutos, I found this class:

[Link](https://github.com/vshivam/call-driver/blob/master/src/com/android/driver/gps_service.java)

I changed the line:

```
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 30*1000*60;
```

to

```
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
```

But I tried to call on my activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyLocationService.class);
    startService(intent);
  }
```

But dont show anything. How can I show the location on Toast for example?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have service definition in your manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyLocationService"></service>
```

And also added permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

You may request these permissions in runtime beginning Android 6.

Comment: I added this lines, but I need to show location on my activity. How can I do it?

Comment: If you want to send data from service back to activity, you need e.g. in activity register broadcastReceiver and from service send broadcast with new location inside `void onLocationChanged(Location location)`. Hope it helps.